# Translate recursive function calls into cost-efficient representation

Tags: algorithm, recursion, optimization

I am trying to use some static analysis tools to check a program with extensive usage of recursive calls. Conceptually, it is something like this:

```
int counter = 0;
int access = 0;

extern int nd ();  // a nondeterministic value 
void compute1();
void compute2();

int get()
{
    static int fpa[2] = {2, 2};  // each function can be called for twice
    int k = nd() % 2;
    if (fpa[k] > 0) {
        fpa[k]--;
        return k+1;
    }
    else
       return 0;
}

void check_r(int* x) {
    if (x == &counter) {
        __VERIFIER_assert(!(access == 2));
        access = 1;
    }
}

void check_w(int* x) {
    if (x == &counter) {
         __VERIFIER_assert((access == 0));
         access = 2;
    }
}

void schedule() {        
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
       int fp = get();
       if (fp == 0)
         return;
       elif (fp == 1)
         compute1();
       elif (fp == 2)
         compute2();
    }
}

void compute1()
{
        // some computations
        ...
        schedule(); // recursive call
        check_w(&counter); // check write access
        ...
}

void compute2()
{
        // some computations
        ...
        schedule(); //recursive call
        check_r(&counter);
        ...
}

int main()
{
        schedule();
        return 0;
}
```

My tentative tests show that due to the recursive call, the static analysis becomes **too slow to terminate**.

While in principle, I can somehow rewrite the recursive call into a [switch statement](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279004/general-way-to-convert-a-loop-while-for-to-recursion-or-from-a-recursion-to-a) or so, but the problem is that before the recursive call `schedule`, `compute1` and `compute2` **functions have performed nontrivial amount of computations already, and it is difficult to save the program context for further usage.**

I have been trapped to optimize this cases for a few days, but just cannot come up with a even ad-hoc solution. Could anyone please provide some comments and suggestions to get rid of the recursive call here? Thank you so much.

Comment: What does the `nd` function do? Does it always return the same value?

Comment: @MitchelPaulin thank you for your comments. So it is a nondeterministic value. Provided by a typical model checker. It evaluates to, well, nondeterministic integers each time.

Comment: If nd can return any integer then in theory this program may never terminate, is that correct? That might even be the likely case considering how many recursive calls you would be stacking here

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Conceptually yes, but in practical it can evaluate into zero. Let me update my question into a `for` loop of five iterations. But that does not solve the problem, right?

Comment: Ah, the static array in the `get` function. Do you use this to ensure compute is only every called 2 times?

Comment: @MitchelPaulin. Right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like all the schedule function is doing is deciding whether to call `compute1` or `compute2` and all the get is doing is ensuring a single function is never called more than twice. I don't think the recursive call from compute to schedule is necessary then since there is never more than two calls. The recursion here seem to imply that every time we can successfully call one of the compute functions we wan't another chance to call compute again

```
void schedule() {
    int chances = 1; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 || chances > 0; i++) { 
       int fp = get();
       if (fp == 0){
           chances--;
           if(chances < 0)
              chances = 0;
           continue; 
       }
       elif (fp == 1){
         compute1(); chances++;
       }
       elif (fp == 2){
         compute2(); chances++;
       }
    }
}

void compute1()
{
        // some computations
        ...
        //schedule(); remove 
        check_w(&counter); // check write access
        ...
}

void compute2()
{
        // some computations
        ...
        //schedule(); remove 
        check_r(&counter);
        ...
}
```

This code is a bit confusing so please clarify if I made any incorrect assumptions